# Solving chain of ODE in Julia

Tags: ode, julia

I am solving two different ODE whose solutions need to be matched. I am currently doing this by hand, which works great, but I would like to automatise this process. The second ODE takes one of its initial conditions and its initial time from the last values of the first solution. I put a MWE below. Now, I have naively tried to put together the first and second ODEs, as I show in the second code below (giving a StackOverflowError). It seems this is not the way to go, though. Does someone know how to do that?

EDIT: the second code is now the solution

```
using DifferentialEquations, Plots

# First ODE, which depends on some parameters

function param_dadp!(s2,d,a0,ϕ₀)
    #ϕ₀ = abs(find_time!(s2,d))
    #ϕ₀=2.0
    function def_dadp!(dv,v,p,ϕ)
        s2,d=p
        α = v[1]
        dv[1] = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*sinh(s2*α*ϕ))/(-α*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*cos(2*d*α)+2*d*cosh(s2*α*ϕ))
    end
    condition(v,ϕ,integrator) = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*sinh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))/(-v[1]*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cos(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cosh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))==1.0
    affect!(integrator) = terminate!(integrator)
    cb = DiscreteCallback(condition,affect!)
    α₀ = [a0]
    tspan = (0,ϕ₀)
    probdadp = ODEProblem(def_dadp!,α₀,tspan,(s2,d))
    soldadp = solve(probdadp,Tsit5(),callback=cb)
end
plot(param_dadp!(81.0,-0.0009,0.083163,2.0))

# Second ODE, which needs initial α and ϕ from the previous solution
function test!(dv,v,p,ϕ)
    α = v[1]
    dα = v[2]
    dv[1] = dα
    dv[2] = 3*(-dα^9/sqrt(2)+dα^8+dα^7/sqrt(2)-dα^6)
end
init = [1.06,1.0] # Put IC by hand
testspan = (0.75,3.0) # Put initial ϕ by hand
prob = ODEProblem(test!,init,testspan)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
plot!(sol,vars=(0,1),xlims=(0,2))
```

````
using DifferentialEquations, Plots

function param_dadp!(s2,d,a0,ϕ₀)
    function def_dadp!(dv,v,p,ϕ)
        s2,d=p
        α = v[1]
        dv[1] = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*sinh(s2*α*ϕ))/(-α*s2*sin(2*d*α)+2*d*cos(2*d*α)+2*d*cosh(s2*α*ϕ))
    end
    condition(v,ϕ,integrator) = (ϕ*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*sinh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))/(-v[1]*s2*sin(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cos(2*d*v[1])+2*d*cosh(s2*v[1]*ϕ))==1.0
    affect!(integrator) = terminate!(integrator)
    cb = DiscreteCallback(condition,affect!)
    α₀ = [a0]
    tspan = (0,ϕ₀)
    probdadp = ODEProblem(def_dadp!,α₀,tspan,(s2,d))
    soldadp = solve(probdadp,Tsit5(),callback=cb)

    function classic!(du,u,p,ϕ)
        αc = u[1]
        dαc = u[2]
        du[1] = dαc
        du[2] = 3*(-dαc^9/sqrt(2)+dαc^8+dαc^7/sqrt(2)-dαc^6)
    end
    init = [last(soldadp);1.0]
    classspan = (last(soldadp.t),ϕ₀)
    probclass = ODEProblem(classic!,init,classspan)
    solclass = solve(probclass,Tsit5())

    solu = append!(soldadp[1,:],solclass[1,:])
    solt = append!(soldadp.t,solclass.t)
    sol = DiffEqArray(solu,solt)
end
plot(param_dadp!(81.0,-0.0009,0.083163,2.0))
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`last(soldadp)` is an array, so `[last(soldadp),1.0]` is a `Vector{Union{Vector{Float64},Float64}}`, i.e. it's like `[[2.0],1.0]`. That's not what you wanted: you wanted `[2.0,1.0]` which means you wanted to use the concatenation operator `;`. `init = [last(soldadp);1.0]` fixes your error.

Now, I don't know what you mean by `sol = soldadp+solclass`: those two time series are not aligned in time, and they hold different numbers of vectors. Did you want to append the plot of the second after the other? Then you can use `plot!` to mutate the plot. Or you can build an array that concatenates the two in the way you're interpreting, but the `+` operator doesn't seem to make much sense here. Either way, it's a `1 x N` object and a `2 x M` object, so it's going to need some user input on what you actually mean by "put these together".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error! 
Indeed, `sol` as such does not make sense. What I really want as output is to extend the function α(ϕ) computed on [0,last(soldadp)] with the α(ϕ) computed on [last(soldadp), ϕ₀] (I will need this function later).  In the end, I'm interested in u[1] only in the second ODE, so I thought I could just add the first component of the two solutions using `sol = append!(soldadp[1,:],solclass[1,:])`, but the plot in output is wrong. I guess I'm not accessing the solutions correctly...

Comment: That should be fine. Just make sure to plot with t too. Also, the default plot uses the interpolation to generate more values, so either use saveat directly or interpolate to get a denser plot.

Comment: How can I specify what t is? I see that the plot generated now goes from 0 to ~40 instead of 0 to 2. Did I lose time somehow when I used append?

Comment: How are you generating the data? `soldadp(0.0:0.1:soldadp.t)` etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you have in mind, but both soldadp and solclass are uType Vector{Vector{Float64}} objects, while sol is only a Vector{Float64} object. So when I use append! to create the sol object, I don't create a uType object, and the tType object which contains the time points is lost, right? If this is correct, then I guess I should create another array `solt=append!(soldadp.t,solclass.t)`, and use it with sol to create a uType somehow. But then, how do I create a Vector{Vector} from two Vector? Using hcat,vcat doesn't seem to be the way. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You're on the right track. And something that may be helpful is the RecursiveArrayTools.jl DiffEqArray for having the t paired with the u for plotting.

Comment: Using `solfinal= DiffEqArray(sol,solt)` works like wonder! Many thanks Chris!